# Mi componente hace 2 llamadas a la api, y la última queda vacía

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

Tengo un custom hook que hace varias llamadas a pokeapi, y como prueba estoy intentando que en mi componente principal se muestre el nombre de cada uno de los pokemones (lógicamente al hacer esas llamadas también agarraría más información, pero para hacer pruebas rápidas solo saco el nombre). El problema es que mi componente principal recibe estas llamadas al cargar la página:

[image: primer renderizado vale null y al hacer la llamada es un array vacío]

El primer null lo entiendo ya que es una operación asíncrona, pero en la segunda llamada que hace no recibe nada, solo un array vacío (el custom hook recibe correctamente la información de la API). Entonces, manualmente guardo mi código para que se renderice y me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: Primer llamada al re-renderizar manualmente el componente: recibo la información correcta, pero se vuelve a llamar a la API y devuelve un array vacío]

Como se puede apreciar, si renderizo manualmente el componente (lo cual no tendría que pasar porque la llamada se tiene que hacer automáticamente al cargar la página) se llama a la api y recibo correctamente la info que quiero en un array, pero luego automáticamente se hace otra llamada que me devuelve un array vacío, lo que hace que mi componente se renderice nuevamente y deje de mostrar la información que quiero (en el ejemplo los nombres de los pokemones).

A continuación dejo el código de la app principal:

```
import useFetch from './servicios/useFetch';

function Pokemones() {
  const data = useFetch();

  console.log(data); //Este es el console.log que se aprecia en las imágenes enviadas

  return (
    <div
      id="pokemones"
      className="d-flex align-content-around justify-content-center flex-wrap gap-3"
      data-tipo="todos"
    >
      {data?.map((pokemones) => (
        <p>{pokemones.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pokemones;
```

Y este es el custom hook que se encarga de hacer las llamadas a la API:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function useFetch() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;
    const pokemones = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
      fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          pokemones.push(response);
        });
    }
    if (!ignore) {
      setData(pokemones);
    }
    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, []);
  return data;
}

export default useFetch;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un race condition. Cuando haces `setData(pokemones)`, el array `pokemones` es aun `[]` ya que el promise de los `fetch` requests aun no han sido resueltos.

Tendrías que modificar tu hook para que solo haga el `setData` una vez que todas los fetch requests al API hayan terminado. Han varias maneras, por ejemplo:

```
function useFetch() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<{ name: string }[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;

    const loadData = async () => {
      // Hacemos un array con todos los fetch request para que las llamadas al API sean en paralelo
      // en vez de usar algo como `for / await`, donde las llamadas se harian sequencialmente,
      // lo que haria que la carga de la pagina mas lenta
      const promises = [...new Array(20)].map((_, i) =>
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i + 1}`).then((res) =>
          res.json()
        )
      );

      const pokemones = await Promise.all(promises);

      setData(pokemones);
    };

    if (!ignore) {
      loadData();
    }

    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return data;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu solución ha funcionado a la perfección. Lo único es que dejé el estado inicial como null. Muchas gracias nuevamente!!!

Comment: @JuanSebastiánAyala chevere. Puedes entonces marcar la respuesta como aceptada y darle al boton de `Esta respuesta es util`